# Can you use dot notation in the key parameter of NSSortDescriptor: sortDescriptorWithKey:?

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-data, ios7

I am anticipating a problem when I have actual data. I have an entity Count that I want to display in a UITableView. Count has a many to one relationship to an entity Service, and Service has an attribute date. I want to sort Count records by Service.data. Can I use @"Service.date" in the key parameter?

TIA
Mark

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The key argument in `sortDescriptorWithKey:...` can be a *key path* that
consists of multiple dot-separated keys.